# Unable to locate cgi-bin for nginx on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I am trying to locate cgi-bin folder for Nginx, which I installed on Mac OSX on my iMac. I am not sure where is it located? I saw another post but it was about the Lion Server. Can somebody tell me where is it on Mac OSX?

Comment: Since CGI isn't supported on nginx - perhaps you just need to select one of these implementations? http://wiki.nginx.org/SimpleCGI also watch for http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

Try finding it by typing this in the terminal:

```
 sudo find / -name cgi-bin | grep nginx
```

Comment: This was the reply I got with adding `sudo` in front of your command, `find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory`, the reason I added `sudo` is because the output I got with your command, I have updated it above.

Comment: @Sam007 according to http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OwCCmeefN_8J:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2787754%3Fstart%3D0%26tstart%3D0+mac+sudo+find+not+a+directory&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a it appears that those errors are normal.  If you didn't see anything else besides them, there is no cgi-bin directory on the system with nginx in its path.  You can try ```sudo find / -name cgi-bin``` to see if one exists anywhere.